# MySQL запрос 1:М не работет условие AND

Tags: mysql, relation

### Таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название',
  `power` decimal(4,1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Мощность',
  `luminous` int(5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Световой поток',
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Цена',
  `hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Хэш картинки',
  `width` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Длина',
  `height` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ширина',
  `depth` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Толщина',
  `weight` decimal(7,3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Вес',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `product_bracing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Товар',
  `bracing` char(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Тип крепления',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_bracing_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=432 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### Пример моего запроса

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`category` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`power` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`luminous` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`price` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`hash` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`width` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`height` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`depth` AS `t0_c9`, `t`.`weight` AS `t0_c10`, `get_bracing`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `get_bracing`.`product_id` AS `t1_c1`, `get_bracing`.`bracing` AS `t1_c2`
FROM `products` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_bracing` `get_bracing` ON (`get_bracing`.`product_id`=`t`.`id`)
WHERE (get_bracing.bracing='cons' AND get_bracing.bracing='lyra' AND category=8)
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Есть таблица `products`, у неё связь с таблицей `products_bracing` - 1:М, в таблице `products_bracing` есть поле 'bracing', которое принимает значение 'cons' или 'lyra'.
Результат выборки всех полей вывдает:

```
products.id | products_bracing.bracing
3 | cons
3 | lyra
4 | cons
5 | cons
```

как составить запрос, чтобы получить продукты, где `products_bracing.bracing = 'cons' and products_bracing.bracing = 'lyra'`, я всегда получаю пустоту почему-то

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска продуктов одновременно с несколькими типами креплений можно один раз приклеить таблицу bracing и выбрать требуемые типы креплений. При этом количество записей в выборке будет соответствовать количеству совпавших условий. Поэтому мы группируем записи до продукта и выбираем те, для которых количество полученных записей равно количеству заданных условий. При склейке нет никакой необходимости использовать LEFT JOIN т.к. нам в любом случае нужны только записи для которых что то есть в bracing.

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`category` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c2`,
       `t`.`power` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`luminous` AS `t0_c4`,`t`.`price` AS `t0_c5`,
       `t`.`hash` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`width` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`height` AS `t0_c8`,
       `t`.`depth` AS `t0_c9`, `t`.`weight` AS `t0_c10`, `get_bracing`.`id` AS `t1_c0`
  FROM `products` `t`
  JOIN `product_bracing` `get_bracing`
    ON `get_bracing`.`product_id`=`t`.`id` and get_bracing.bracing in('lyra','cons')
 WHERE category=8
 GROUP BY t.id
HAVING count(1)=2
 ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Comment: То что нужно. Подскажие какую роль здесь выполняет 
**HAVING count(1)=2** `код`

Comment: @K.Lobastov Как раз самую основную, считает количество записей, т.е. количество совпавших условий. Так что при добавлении типов в `bracing in()` вместо 2 было кол-во значений внутри in. Кстати, вы сказали у вас 7 подобных таблиц. Рассмотрите вариант с 1 таблицей в которой на одно поле больше "тип условия" (которое будет обозначать вашу текущую таблицу одну из 8) и собирайте в ней все. тогда отбор подобным запросом будет просто делать

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю задачу, нужно выдать товары, у которых присутствует и тип  крепления `cons` и тип крепления `lyra`
В таком случае, нужно сменить `left join` на `inner join` и сделать два джойна к таблице `products_bracing`:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`category` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c2`, 
`t`.`power` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`luminous` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`price` AS `t0_c5`, 
`t`.`hash` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`width` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`height` AS `t0_c8`, 
`t`.`depth` AS `t0_c9`, `t`.`weight` AS `t0_c10`, `get_bracing_cons`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, 
`get_bracing_cons`.`product_id` AS `t1_c1`, `get_bracing_lyra`.`bracing` AS `t1_c2`
FROM `products` `t`
INNER JOIN `product_bracing` `get_bracing_cons` ON 
(`get_bracing_cons`.`product_id`=`t`.`id` AND get_bracing_cons.bracing='cons' AND category=8)
INNER JOIN `product_bracing` `get_bracing_lyra` ON 
(`get_bracing_lyra`.`product_id`=`t`.`id` AND get_bracing_lyra.bracing='lyra' AND category=8)
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Comment: Круто, это работает) Но ещё вопрос,без дополнительного джоина не решить эту задачу? получается если есть много типов крепления, на каждый из них добавлять связь?

Comment: Тут хотелось бы всё-таки узнать - а что нужно получить в итоге? :) Опять же, если я правильно понимаю задачу - получить список светильников, у которых присутствует определенный перечень креплений, то делаем cross join товаров на таблицу с этим перечнем, потом left join с типами креплений по id товара и типу крепления, потом смотрим те записи, где нет ни одного NULL в ID крепления.

Comment: Ну и неплохо бы нормализовать таблицу креплений, выделив справочник ;)

Comment: Есть ещё таблицы, схожие с product_bracing(штук 7) где типов значения может быть не 2, а достаточно много. Получается при фильтрации товаров, мы делаем оочень много джоинов, это норма для данной задачи?

Answer (score 0):

тут ошибка

```
WHERE (get_bracing.bracing='cons' AND get_bracing.bracing='lyra' AND category=8)
```

должно быть

```
WHERE ((get_bracing.bracing='cons' OR get_bracing.bracing='lyra') AND category=8)
```

поле одновременно не может принимать 2 значения `cons` и `lyra`, что бы выбрать оба, нужно использовать `OR`

---

даже лучше так

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`,            `t`.`category` AS `t0_c1`, 
       `t`.`title` AS `t0_c2`,         `t`.`power` AS `t0_c3`, 
       `t`.`luminous` AS `t0_c4`,      `t`.`price` AS `t0_c5`, 
       `t`.`hash` AS `t0_c6`,          `t`.`width` AS `t0_c7`, 
       `t`.`height` AS `t0_c8`,        `t`.`depth` AS `t0_c9`, 
       `t`.`weight` AS `t0_c10`,
       `get_bracing`.`id` AS `t1_c0`,  `get_bracing`.`product_id` AS `t1_c1`, 
       `get_bracing`.`bracing` AS `t1_c2`
  FROM `products` `t`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_bracing` `get_bracing` 
       ON  `get_bracing`.`product_id`=`t`.`id` 
       AND (get_bracing.bracing='cons' OR get_bracing.bracing='lyra')
 WHERE category = 8
 ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

В этом примере, при `JOIN` вы уже выбераете только те записи где есть значения

Comment: Согласен, поле одновременно не принимает 2 значения, но ведь с таким запросом я получу ещё товары, где либо 'cons', либо 'lyra' ? а нужно выполнение 2-x условий сразу